# Why ARIMA function return model ARMA?

Tags: python, arima

I tried to fit model by use ARIMA function. But when I fit model, it return model ARMA. Is it because of my data set?

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA, ARIMAResults
model = ARIMA(df['Sale'], order=(0,0,0))
results = model.fit()
results.summary()
```

PS.df is my dataframe, I try to use weekly data and daily data. But it still return ARMA on both data sets.

[image: This is the result from fitting model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is happening because you are intaking the 'd' parameter=0 (centermost parameter in order=(0,0,0)) which is the only difference between ARMA & ARIMA. If d=0, then ARIMA=ARMA
You can further explore it here: https://medium.com/data-science-in-your-pocket/linear-forecasting-models-for-univariate-time-series-prediction-9bff14c2b3b3